# Remove non alpha-numeric charcters from a URL except hyphens

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm very new to this.

I'd like to remove non alpha-numeric characters from a URL except hyphens.

This seems to work.

```
$string = preg_replace( "/[^0-9a-zA-Z-]/", '', $string);
```

Does it look bombproof to you?

Thanks

Comment: Your solution already answers your own question. The regex you provide accomplishes what you're setting out to do.

Comment: Seems good. You could also use `"/[^0-9A-Z-]/i"` where `i` is the ignore case flag so that `A-Z` also matches `a-z`. Bombproof? If that's what you're only trying to do, very likely, but I'm a bit confused as to why you would do that, especially if you have something like `http://www.google.com` becoming `httpwwwgooglecom`.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I'd like to use product names as part of my URLs, but to exclude characters which may feature in the name and break the url such as '/'. I'd like to be sure that it will work with 100% of the product names.

Comment: This question is requesting a [codereview.se].